# No functions in System.out

Tags: intellij-idea, println

So today I installed IntelliJ on my computer, Trying out some code I realize `System.out.println` shows println in red, the same goes for print. IntelliJ doesn't even show any suggestions after `System.out.`. I have installed jdk_1.8.0 and am running IntelliJ ideaIU-13.1.1

{edit}

fixed it by re-downloading jdk.

Answer (score 0):

You must go File > Project structure > Project. At field "Project SDK" choose jdk_1.8.0 you have installed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but sadly I've already tried that, twice. IntelliJ accepts String as a thing and doesnt complain about a lack of any SDK